# Property 'downloadURL' not found on object of type 'FIRStorageMetadata *' - Getting this error when trying to build a Flutter project

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I'm trying to build a Flutter project on Xcode with firebase installed. I'm getting the following error: `Property 'downloadURL' not found on object of type 'FIRStorageMetadata *'`

This is being caused by the following section in the FirebaseStoragePlugin.m file:

```
  NSString *path = call.arguments[@"path"];
  NSDictionary *metadataDictionary = call.arguments[@"metadata"];
  FIRStorageMetadata *metadata;
  if (![metadataDictionary isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
    metadata = [self buildMetadataFromDictionary:metadataDictionary];
  }
  FIRStorageReference *fileRef = [[FIRStorage storage].reference child:path];
  [fileRef putData:data
          metadata:metadata
        completion:^(FIRStorageMetadata *metadata, NSError *error) {
          if (error != nil) {
            result(error.flutterError);
          } else {
            // Metadata contains file metadata such as size,
            // content-type, and download URL.
            NSURL *downloadURL = metadata.downloadURL;  <---------------- This line
            result(downloadURL.absoluteString);
          }
        }];
}
```

Since I didn't generate this code, I don't particularly want to edit it as it should really be working out of the box. I've tried to change the method to see whether later versions of Firebase might only accept another function but to no avail. What shall I do in this situation? Should I perhaps try to rebuild the project with a higher version of Firebase or is there a one line fix?

Answer (score 1):

The `downloadURL` was removed from the [`StorageMetadata` class](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/StorageMetadata) in [May 2018](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#cloud-storage_20). If your native iOS code still uses that, it's high time to find an updated SDK or update your code to match the documentation on [uploading a file and getting its download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_from_data_in_memory).

If you're using the [FlutterFire binding libraries](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview), upgrade to the latest version (as I definitely don't see any reference to `metadata.downloadURL` in its [current code base](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/search?q=metadata.downloadURL)). If you're using another library, check if the latest version of that solves the problem - or otherwise consider switching to the FlutterFire libraries as those are quite actively maintained.